# Discovering where a circular dependency is

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I've got a project that I was attempting to do some refactoring in and I split out some windows forms controls into their own project inside of my solution.  I'm now getting a circular dependency error when trying to setup the required references.

My question is.  Does VS (or some other tool) have anything in it that will help discover where the issue lies?  I thought I had refactored out the issue, but this is obviously not the case.

Comment: How do you know that the issue is circular dependancy?

Comment: You wrote "I'm *not* getting a circular dependency error". Did you mean *now*?

Comment: > I'm now getting a circular dependency error when trying to setup the required references.

Do you mean VS don't let you add an assembly reference? Have you looked at the NDepend capabilities to detect dependencies cycles: http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependencyCycle

Comment: Sorry for the verbage screwup.  Yes When I try to add a reference to the new project after refactoring the code I'm told that I can't as it will have a circular dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am misreading this, VS **is** telling you where the circular dependency lies just by telling you that you cannot add a reference. The project you are trying to add a reference to will already be referenced in the project that you are coming from (I think I worded that right...if not, here is the example)

ie.

- ProjectA holds a reference to ProjectB
- ProjectB cannot hold a reference to ProjectA, so you get a circular dependency error

As to trying to find the exact place(s) where you use ProjectB in ProjectA, so that you could switch the reference. I would just remove the reference and compile...all references will now throw errors.

Comment: Good thought.  When I get back to work I'll try and look at it this way.  This problem just happened to pop up as I was walking out the door so I thought I'd ask the masses as I had never seen the actual error before.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Profiler tool does this very well if you have VS >= Premium edition.

Comment: Using Visual Studio Pro 2012 RC